# Does nudging an exact differential equation nudge or destroy the identity integrating factor?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, integrating-factor

This question will be related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155946/integrating-factor-techniques-for-exact-ode), if for no other reason because a positive answer to the latter would likely help to solve the former.

Consider the differential equation $(y)\ dx + (x)\ dy = 0$.  It is already exact, so we can think of the multiplicative identity, $u(x) = 1$, as an integrating factor.  We can also observe by separating variables that $u(x) = \frac{1}{xy}$ is an integrating factor, yielding $(\frac{1}{x})\ dx + (\frac{1}{y})\ dy = 0$.  From here, $u(x) = xy$ allows us to return to the original form, so we can toggle freely between the two, and both produce the same solution, $y = \frac{C}{x}$.

Now instead consider the inexact equation $(y)\ dx + (x + \epsilon\ x)\ dy = 0$, for some small value of $\epsilon$.  By separating variables, we find the integrating factor $u(x) = \frac{1}{(x + \epsilon x)y}$, and the solution $y = \frac{C}{x^{\frac{1}{1 + \epsilon}}}$, which respectively are very close to $u(x) = \frac{1}{xy}$ and $ = \frac{C}{x}$ from the previous problem.  However, the original inexact form has $\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \epsilon$, which is very close to $0$.  Does this imply (not only for this problem, but in general) that an integrating factor very close to $u(x) = 1$ exists, or is the nearby exact form destroyed entirely when we nudge $\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}$ even by a tiny amount?

Comment: Consider slightly changing the title of the question. If I were to answer the question in title, I would say that exactness is a fragile property (non structurally stable, using terminology from dynamical systems): you can always perturb the exact equation with non-degenerate extremum of potential and get an equation which can't be exact at all. However, the question in your post is a bit different.

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right.  Is this any better?

Comment: Seems good to me :) Also, don't forget that user gets a notification about a comment is when you mention them with @ .